# System Renviron cannot find

Tags: r, installation, shared-libraries, fedora, renviron

I reinstalled my system (Fedora36), because of some hardware issues. A tried to run my C script embedded with some R-code which was running perfectly on the previous system (Fedora35). The make file runs smoothly, but running the program oneself I have two (or maybe they are related to each other) error messages:

- cannot find system Renviron Fatal error unable to open base package and
- sh: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24

The R is running from the command line, the R home directory is set and the system has libtinfo.so.6. Everything updated. The same problem appeared using Fedora 38. No missing dependency based on the ldd's report. (Neither the libtinfo.so.6 file.)
And in that moment I ran out of ideas ... :(

Anyone have any ideas what could be done?

Thanks, Fiser